# Select Spills Over Display Table Cell Parent Container

Tags: html, css

I can't think of a better title! I have a pseudo-table structure using HTML `div` elements which contains a `select` input field:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <select>
            <option>
                This is an option with a 
                really, really long value!
            </option>
            <option>
                Here is a normal value.
            </option>
            <option>
                And if this value is extremely 
                long, it stretches the parent 
                select even further!
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">Cell 2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Cell 3</div>
</div>
```

This is styled using CSS' `display:table-cell`, as follows:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid #f60;
}
```

The problem is that the select spills over the parent container if the `option` value is too long. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dnBWD/1/

I can sort-of resolve the spilling issue by removing `table-layout: fixed`, but I need the columns to be equal width, at 33%. How can I contain the select in the table-cell element?

**~ edit ~**

I humbly apologise, I forgot to mention:

I need the `select` element to occupy the full width of the cell (100%) always, and the cell is responsive; it stretches with the viewport.

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated side note... it seems like you are trying to re-invent the `<table>` using `<div>`s and CSS.  Before you get too deep into this are you sure you don't really want a `<table>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust this to suit your needs (e.g. set externally in a CSS declaration by tag/id/class):

```
<select style="width:150px;">
```

or if you want a dynamic width (see revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KV7rR/):

```
<select style="width:100%;">
```

It will force the closed select list to render at a smaller size.

When opened, the browser will show the full, wider list.

*Notes:* IE in particular (especially older versions) will not expand the dropped select list content to show everything (e.g. it will get clipped)  Before suggesting any hacks, what version(s) of IE do you *need* to support?

Comment: Thx scunliffe, I've updated the question with an important note I forgot about responsive requirements! IE8+ compatibility is required.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, the solution to this was very simple, just needed to add a `max-width` to the select element. Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/KV7rR/1/

Thanks everyone.

**~ edit ~**

`max-width` does not work in all browsers, found `width` to be the correct solution; thanks to the answer above.